# Poker books for people with short attention spans

Tags: books

I was wondering if anybody knew of good Poker books that are easy to read. I have tried reading the regular popular books but I find that halfway through a 40 page chapter my brain kind of turns off and I realize I haven't soaked in any of it and I'm wasting my time.

One poker book I really enjoyed reading was Daniel Negreanu's Hold'em Wisdom for all players due to the short chapters and the to-the-point writing style. The problem is that these books are usually not too advanced and directed towards beginners.

Does anyone know any know of any intermediate-advanced level poker books that follow a similar writing style?

Comment: Phil Gordon Little Green book.  But I think the advanced books are required for advanced play.

Comment: Obviously but I am looking for advanced books that still feel like easy reading. Obviously a niche but I hope it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference for people, I am now reading a book called Easy Game by Andrew Seidman, and it is an excellent book with about 3-4 page long chapters. Perfect for those little reading sessions.

Answer (score 2):

I have never read that book from Daniel Negreanu, but in general books that are that old are a bit dated. You might still be able to beat an easy $1-$2 game with what are often just tight-aggressive strategies, but there are better books these days.

I really like all of Ed Miller's books, and they're oriented towards the small to medium stakes no-limit player. They also represent what's more current in terms of low to mid-stakes poker thought than anything published in 2007. You can find his books and articles at http://www.notedpokerauthority.com/, or get the books on Amazon.  I really liked Small Stakes and Playing the Player as good starting points.

Another relatively recent book I liked is Moorman's Book of Poker. It's a hand-by-hand analysis of some online tournament runs, and each hand highlights some interesting and relevant aspects of tournament play. If you like short nuggets of wisdom gleaned from specific hands, this one might be for you.

You might also describe what it was that you thought was boring about the books you didn't like.

Comment: It wasn't anything specifically that I found boring in them. I think it was just that long chapters are generally tackling broader ideas and after a while, my attention span is completely used up. I'll look at those books, thanks!

Comment: If "short attention span" is a key issue, then I think I'd try Moorman's book.  You can read as little as a few pages at a time and still get something useful out of it.  Of course, it won't delve into why a concept is important as much, but it does a good job of helping identify scenarios where it's important to think about specific things.

Comment: Ok,  I'll check it out. That is the key issue. Thank God for chip shuffling or I'd lose my mid at the poker table.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the Harrington on Hold'em series of books. I've just completed volume I and volume II, although I'm not a huge fan of reading! However, I found the books easy to read - you are given theory followed by examples throughout the books. I also found they were really well broken up into digestible chunks, which meant I could read a bit, put the book down, and then easily pick up where I left from on the next reading session.

Some of the other [better poker books](http://whichpokersite.co.uk/poker-articles/three-best-poker-books/) I have read are:

- Doyle Brunson’s Super System: A Course in Power Poker!
- The Theory of Poker: A Professional Poker Player Teaches You How to Think Like One
- The Mental Game of Poker

However, I do not think you will find these 3 as digestible as Harrington on Hold 'em!